# Serialize a subset of environment variables

Tags: bash, sh, busybox

I'm trying to export some environment variables for use by a TomCat process.

There's a few ways to do this (I know how to solve the *overall* problem), but it bugged me that I didn't know how to do this particular shell task.

Tomcat recommends that all your environment customizations should be exported by `"$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh"`.

This whole thing is gonna be stuffed into a Docker container, so the only parameterizability will be via Docker env variables (let's assume for this task that I don't want to use volume mounts or create `setenv.sh` during the build process).

First, observe that `docker run -e` can be used to pass environment into the container:

```
 docker run -eMY_VAR=SUP alpine env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=a528b6fc264b
MY_VAR=SUP
no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16
HOME=/root
```

If we wanted to copy *all* of that env into `setenv.sh`, it's as simple as:

```bash
SETENV="/usr/local/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh"
echo '#!/bin/sh' > "$SETENV"
echo 'export -p' >> "$SETENV"
env >> "$SETENV"
```

But copying *everything* somewhat defeats the point of `setenv.sh` -- which is, to give your tomcat process a *clean* environment, with only *intentional* customizations.

---

So, we can agree on a convention for "which env vars are ones that we want to pass through to `setenv.sh`". Everything prefixed with `MY_`.

And *now* we get to an interesting shell problem.

```bash
env | grep '^MY_' | sed 's/^MY_/EXPORT /'
```

This gets us pretty close. Output looks like:

```
 docker run -e MY_VAR=hey alpine sh -c "env | grep '^MY_' | sed 's/^MY_/EXPORT /'" 
EXPORT VAR=hey
```

So, we've selected from the `env` command: only env vars prefixed with `MY_`. And we can redirect that output to `setenv.sh`.

Why do I say "pretty close"? Looks like we're done, right?

---

Try this for size:

```
 docker run -e MY_VAR='multi                                                    
quote> line  
quote> string' alpine sh -c "env | grep '^MY_' | sed 's/^MY_/EXPORT /'"
EXPORT VAR=multi
```

The script only worked for a simple subset of possibilities. i.e. **we only managed to export the first line of our multi-line string.**

For your convenience: env output for multi-line strings looks like this:

```
 docker run -e MY_VAR='multi
line
string' alpine env                                              
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=0d0afaac6bec
MY_VAR=multi
line
string
no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16
HOME=/root
```

I hesitate to try and tackle this using awk; there may be further string escaping complications that I have not considered.

**I wonder whether there's a better way altogether to select & serialize a subset of exported environment?**

---

**EDIT**: I negligently tagged this as a `bash` question, when really my intention was to pose an `sh` question. Specifically my intention is to get something that will work with no dependencies other than those that come with the alpine docker image. i.e. BusyBox `sh`, `sed`, `grep`, `awk`, `env`.

I've retained the `bash` tag so as not to punish the initial answer that was submitted when this was a `bash`-only question.

But I will give preference to an `sh`-compatible answer, and in particular to one that works with just the BusyBox UNIX utils.

Comment: Why are you doing `echo 'export -p' >> "$SETENV"` and `env >> "$SETENV"` when you want to copy only few hand-coded env variables to docker container.

Comment: @anubhava, that's prefaced with the explanation, "If we wanted to copy _all_ of that env". Rather than jumping straight into the complicated problem: I demonstrated how to completely solve _part_ of the problem (i.e. serialising environment). A StackOverflow question should show the bits that one _did_ get working, then highlight the problem constraint upon which one is blocked.

Comment: @anubhava, I'd be **very** wary of suggesting folks parse `env`. Consider `CGI_X_MY_EVIL_HEADER=$'foo\nLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/bar.so'` as an example intended to inform.

Comment: it seems there's no suitable filtering mechanism (except with non-POSIX extensions), so I suspect that parsing will be necessary (and difficult). it's true that malicious env is possible, so probably if we use a parsing approach, we should only trust it in systems where we control the inputs (for example, the use-case described in the question — where an operator we trust is producing the shell arguments manually).

Comment: Needing to trust your arguments is unfortunate. It's a common use case to have arguments derived from dynamically-generated filenames, for example. One of the worst data loss events I've seen was caused by a bad pointer in a library used by a program that dumped garbage into a buffer used as a filename (that "couldn't ever" contain anything but hex digits, so the folks writing the script that later used that name didn't bother to quote). It wasn't even intentionally malicious, but the result was literally multiple TB of backups of data used to support customer billing being lost.

Comment: point taken. so far I'm thinking that a low-dependency production-safe solution is unlikely to emerge. it remains an interesting shell scripting question, but for my own use-case I'm going to implement parameterization through a safer mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need several things:

- Enumerate the environment variables and select a subset.
- For each selected environment variable, emit sh code that sets the variable to the desired value.

You can use `export -p` if you want to export all variables in a form that can be read back in, but parsing it to select only certain variables is harder. One way to make use of `export -p` is to unset the other variables. This only works if none of the environment variables is read-only, but you can work around that by running a separate shell instance (as opposed to a subshell).

To gather the list of variables to unset, you only need to get a superset of the list of all environment variables, and remove the ones you want to keep. You can easily do that by filtering the `env` output. I do that with a simple `grep`, you may want to use more complex code if your criteria for inclusion are more complex than “begins with a specific prefix”.

The occasional false positive due to a variable containing a newline followed by a valid variable name and an equal sign will only lead to calling `unset` on a non-existent variable, which does nothing. The desired variables are removed from the exclusion list, so the final output will never omit a desired variable.

```
excluded=$(env | LC_ALL=C sed -n 's/^\([A-Z_a-z][0-9A-Z_a-z]*\)=.*/\1/p' |
           grep -v 'MY_')
sh -c 'unset $1; export -p' sh "$excluded" >setenv.sh
```

Dash prints an extra `export PATH` (with no value) if `PATH` was in the environment when it was invoked. If that bothers you, change `sh -c …` to `(unset PATH; sh -c …)`.

Comment: This allows multi-line values inside allowed variables to modify the exclusion list. I'm not sure that's the only bug, either -- there are more places where it smells like there's likely to be room for unexpected behavior, but this doesn't look easy to analyze.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But it doesn't matter! The exclusion list needs to contain all of the variables that must not be exported. Adding spurious items to that list doesn't invalidate that property. The exclusion list needs to omit the variables that must be kept, and the grep filter takes care of that.

Comment: @Birchlabs No. `MY_OTHER_VAR` is not unset, it's exported correctly.

Comment: you're correct; just tried it. I've deleted my comment where I asserted that "injection of `MY_OTHER_VAR=` into the beginning of some line within a value" could cause false positive unsettings of vars that we care about.

Comment: So, this survived my malicious attempts at injection (for the following examples, `\n` should be substituted with a literal line break, and these inputs should be used as args to `docker run -it alpine sh`). I tried making it exclude more variables than it was supposed to: `-e MY_VAR="hey\nMY_OTHER_VAR=ho" -e MY_OTHER_VAR=no`. I also tried making it include variables that didn't exist:  `-e MY_VAR="multi'\nexport MY_INJECTED='val"`. It survived all. It meets the requirement, "use only `alpine+sh+busybox`". It's an interesting approach. For these reasons: I've elected this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`alpine` image doesn't ship with `bash`.

You can use this script to extract all `MY_*` variables including newline variables:

```
docker run -e MY_FOO=bar -e MY_VAR="multi' export MY_INJECTED='val" -e MY_VAR2=$'multi
0MY_line=val
string' alpine sh -c "awk -v RS='\06' -F= '/^MY_/{k=\$1; sub(/^[^=]+=/, \"\"); 
gsub(/\047/, \"\047\\\\\\047\047\"); printf \"export %s=\047%s\047\n\", k, \$0
}' /proc/self/environ"
```

This will output:

```
export MY_FOO='bar'
export MY_VAR='multi'\'' export MY_INJECTED='\''val'
export MY_VAR2='multi
0MY_line=val
string'
```

Here is how `awk` works:

- `-v RS='\6'`: sets record separator as `\6` works for nul byte as well (assuming you don't have `\6` in value)
- `-F=`: sets field separator as `=`
- `/^MY_/`: Only process records starting with `MY_`
- store variable name or `$1` in variable `k`
- Using `sub` function get part after `=` in `$0`
- Using `print` format output so that it can be used in `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh` file.
- `\047` is for printing single quote

Comment: bravo! that meets all the constraints expressed in my question. could you please elaborate on what the awk is doing?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't fare so well when `line` is replaced with `line=val` (that is, having a literal `=` inside the second line of the variable's value).

Comment: This doesn't properly quote variable values containing single quotes. It also prints out spurious statements `export foo=bar` if `foo=bar` happens to be a line in the value of a multiline variable.

Comment: It's setting `0`, not NUL, as the record separator. Putting `0MY_line=val` in the data confuses it as one would expect.

Comment: Ah that's right. `awk` on BusyBox doesn't like `\0` as `RS` so used `\6` now.

Comment: good work. handles line breaks nicely. but it's vulnerable to single quotes. consider: `-e MY_VAR="multi'\nexport MY_INJECTED='val"`. [I can't show line breaks here, so replace the \n with a literal line break]. that kind of formatting can be used to inject additional variable assignments.

Comment: You still haven't got the quoting right. You're using double quotes, which is difficult to get right: several characters keep their special meaning inside double quotes, but you can't just put backslashes everywhere. Use single quotes instead, they're easier to work with. You only need to escape embedded single quotes as `'\''`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming GNU grep:

```
grep --null '^MY_' </proc/self/environ
```

...will emit your environment variables in NUL-delimited form (newlines intact).

---

Similarly, if you have bash:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' vardef; do
  [[ $vardef = MY_* ]] && printf '%s\0' "$vardef"
done </proc/self/environ
```

Note that if these variables were set in the same shell session, you may need to create a subprocess for `/proc/self/environ` to be updated:

```
(while IFS= read -r -d '' vardef; do
   [[ $vardef = MY_* ]] && printf '%s\0' "$vardef"
 done </proc/self/environ)
```

Comment: nice approach! sadly we cannot assume GNU grep (I expressed that I am looking for an answer that works with busybox grep). but this is a nice solution for certain environments (where `env -0` is unavailable, but GNU grep is available).

Comment: I've edited to provide an approach that'll work without GNU grep (though it *does* require a shell with `read -d`, which is a non-POSIX extension).

Comment: thanks for adding that example. as you say: it's useful if bash is available, but not GNU grep (for example on a fresh macOS installation). Nahuel Fouilleul [provided a shorter command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45713231/5257399) for the same constraints (uses `declare` to do the filter). my preferred answer would be to have fewer dependencies: sh and busybox utils only.

Comment: I'm hesitant to use `declare` for the purpose -- `declare -p` guarantees that it'll output content in such a way that another instance of bash (of the same version or later) can `eval` it, but that doesn't mean you'll be able to read it consistently from a different language, particularly as shell versions change. (BTW, `declare` isn't doing the filtering, just the output; the `${!prefix*}` expansion is generating a string with a list of variable names; having it unquoted means that string then is split into a group of separate arguments).

Comment: This only solves part of the problem (detecting the variable names, but you also need to print the values afterward), and only with tools that aren't available on stripped-down systems (bash, GNU grep).

Comment: @Gilles, NUL-delimited serialization is far and away the best format to use for the job, and that's the format this (like `/proc/self/environ`) uses out-of-the-box.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But shells suck at dealing with null bytes. If you start from null-delimited data, you need to convert from null-delimited to shell syntax at some point.

Comment: @Gilles, baseline POSIX shells are bad at that, sure, but that's why I'm explicitly providing a bash-centric answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
declare -p ${!MY_*}
```

and

```
declare -p ${!MY_*} | sed -r 's/^declare (-[^ ]*)* MY_/export /'
```

or

```
declare -p ${!MY_*} | sed 's/^declare \(-[^ ]*\)* MY_/export /'
```

EDIT posix compliant version :

some `env` or `printenv` accept `-0` option to end each output line by `\0` rather than a newline. Thus

```
env -0  | perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/="\0";$\="\n";$q="\047"}next unless /^MY_/;chomp;s/$q/$q\\$q$q/;s/=/=$q/;s/$/$q/;print'
```

How it works

```
$/ : input record separator
$\ : output record separator
$q : variable to store single quote (\047) because of surrounding single quotes in command
next : to filter "MY_" variables
chomp : removes the input separator
s/// : quote substitution
```

EDIT: variation of perl version in posix shell

```
env -0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'for entry; do [[ $entry = MY_* ]] || continue; printf "%s=\047%s\047\n" "${entry%%=*}" "$(echo "${entry#*=}" | sed '\''s/\x27/\x27\\\x27\x27/g'\'' )"; done' -
```

Comment: I confirm that this works perfectly for bash. nice! however I must confess that I have misclassified this question. I've retagged as `sh`, since that's what the lightweight `alpine` image ships with. I appreciate that your answer was valid in the original context of the question, so if no `sh` answer is forthcoming within a day or so: I'll rebrand this as a `bash` question and elect yours as the answer.

Comment: thanks; your edit makes this compatible with `sh`, but admittedly introduces a dependency on perl, and on a certain implementation of `env`. I've rewritten the question to clarify that the main requirement is to use the utilities that ship in the alpine Linux Docker image -- i.e. the BusyBox UNIX utils. sorry for moving the goal-posts again; I underestimated how barebones an `alpine+busybox+sh` stack can be. probably the only way is to use awk. I am still prepared to accept your answer after some time if none matches the more stringent requirements, as I unfairly underspecified the question.

Comment: nice. it removes the perl dependency. and even works without awk. but `-0` is not implemented by BusyBox `env`. one way to test behaviour against a lightweight stack — `alpine+busybox+sh` — is to open a shell inside an alpine image, like so: `docker run -it -e MY_VAR='somevalue' alpine sh` (and to include a line break inside the string `'somevalue'`).

Comment: `"${!MY_@}"` might be a slightly better choice. Sure, we shouldn't have variable names that would undergo string-splitting or glob expansion, but there might be an `IFS` value set that contains `_` or another legal character.

Comment: re: perl+POSIX -- `[[` isn't POSIX syntax; presumably that should be `case $entry in MY_*) :;; *) continue;; esac`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, of course, i replied rapidly and didn't check, now i see there's yet a lot of other good answers